# Django saves only after view is completed successfully

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.5.4 and seems like it has this debug setting which causes the save method not to save until the view has completed successfully. Which makes a user-registration-and-login-right-after feature impossible.

I tried to set `DEBUG=False`, didn't help.
It happens with every model.
I'm using MySQL but I'm pretty sure thats not relevant at all.
I'm using a email-auth-backend, here it is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class EmailBackend():
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
```

The code I'm using to save is pretty usual:

```
user = User()
user.first_name = full_name[0]
user.last_name = ' '.join(full_name[1:])
user.email = data['email']
user.username = create_username(user.first_name, user.last_name)
user.set_password(data['password'])
user.save()

auth_form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST or None)
if auth_form.is_valid():
    login(request, auth_form.get_user())
```

I also looked up on Django docs for version 1.5.4 and majors but didn't find anything as well.

Now, what might be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django saves immediately, but when `TransactionMiddleware` is enabled, the *transaction* is committed only when the request ends.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests

> The recommended way to handle transactions in Web requests is to tie them to the request and response phases via Django’s `TransactionMiddleware`.
>
> It works like this: When a request starts, Django starts a transaction. If the response is produced without problems, Django commits any pending transactions. If the view function produces an exception, Django rolls back any pending transactions.
>
> To activate this feature, just add the `TransactionMiddleware` middleware to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting

You can either [commit manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually) or turn [autocommit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.autocommit) on for the entire view:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.autocommit
def viewfunc(request):
    ....
```

You can also remove `TransactionMiddleware` from your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really didn't find anything on the web. Although this might be a simple issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db import transaction
with transaction.commit_on_success():
    user.save()
```

more about [Database transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/).

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up about TransactionMiddleware
From the Django docs:

> In Django 1.6, TransactionMiddleware is **deprecated** and replaced by ATOMIC_REQUESTS. While the general behavior is the same, there are two differences.
>
> With the previous API, it was possible to switch to autocommit or to commit explicitly anywhere inside a view. Since ATOMIC_REQUESTS relies on atomic() which enforces atomicity, this isn’t allowed any longer. However, at the toplevel, it’s still possible to avoid wrapping an entire view in a transaction. To achieve this, decorate the view with non_atomic_requests() instead of autocommit().
>
> The transaction middleware applied not only to view functions, but also to middleware modules that came after it. For instance, if you used the session middleware after the transaction middleware, session creation was part of the transaction. ATOMIC_REQUESTS only applies to the view itself.